# Add all matches with select2 4.0.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'd like to make it easy for user's to select all matches when using select2.

**The Existing Code**

I currently have the following code using select2 4.0.3 and jquery 1.11.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
```

A complete jsfiddle of the code https://jsfiddle.net/rwinch/t7112qcc/5/

**Behavior I desire**

Can someone help me to modify the above code to allow the user to easily select all matches. For example, if the screen looks like:

[image]

And the user presses CTRL+A and then enter, then the result is:

[image]

Comment: Does not happen with me in Chrome 52

Comment: @Rayon What does not happen? If you are saying it does not select the values that are matching, then yes that is expected. I was just trying to provide the code I have right now (not a solution). I have updated my question to make this more clear.

Comment: _"result is"_ or _"result should be"_ ? Dear, Please mention what is happening and What you are expecting to happen...

Comment: @Rayon The existing behavior is exactly as the jsfiddle demonstrates. Nothing happens when CTRL+A is pressed. The behavior I desire is clearly stated in the section titled "Behavior I desire"

Comment: it seems the official documentation does not offer such events, so no obvious way to get the currently matched elements https://select2.github.io/options.html#events

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've forked your fiddle, so you can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/alienpavlov/z34qczr6/1/

```js
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();

$(document).on('keyup', ".select2-search__field", function(e) {
    //if Ctrl+A pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
        //Select only filtered results
        $.each($(".select2-results__options").find('li'), function(i, item) {
            $(".js-example-basic-multiple > option:contains('" + $(item).text() + "')").prop("selected", "selected");
        });
        //Remove entered letters and close suggestions
        $(this).val("").click();
        //Select with select2
        $(".js-example-basic-multiple").trigger("change");
    }
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
    I'd like an easy way for users to add all matches. For example the user
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Enters "A"</li>
    <li>Presses CTRL+A or Meta+A all matches are selected</li>
    <li>Presses enter all matches are added</li>
</ul>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

I've left all the comments in the code

Comment: Thanks! Although this doesn't use the official APIs, I don't suspect this is currently possible given the select2 documentation.

Comment: Yes it doesn't, because I didn't find any options for that. So my solutions is kind of hacky, but it works.

Comment: I like your solution more than any other answers to similar questions on StackOverflow. But I would like to ask, do you have an idea how to expand your snippet to work also for "deselect all"?